# Met c++ code " #define ELEMENT(TYPE, FIELD)"

Tags: c++

```
#define ELEMENT(TYPE, FIELD)\
      bool get##FIELD(TYPE *field) const throw()\
      { \
          return x_->get##FIELD(y_, field);\
      } \
```

I never met code like this before.

First, why do we put code in `#define`, is it a macro? So, I can use `ELEMENT()` later in other places?

Second, what is `##`?  What I can find online is "The ## operator takes two separate tokens and pastes them together to form a single token. The resulting token could be a variable name, class name or any other identifier."

Could someone tell me how I should know what this kind of code works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ELEMENT()` is a preprocessor macro, which is just a fancy way to replace one piece of text with another piece of text before the compiler is invoked.  At the site where a macro is invoked, it is replaced with the text content of the macro.  If the macro has parameters, each parameter is replaced with the text that the caller passed in to the macro.

In this case, the `TYPE` parameter is being used as-is within the macro text, whereas the `FIELD` parameter is being concatenated with `get` via `##` concatenation to produce a new token identifier `get<FIELD>`.

`ELEMENT()` can be used like this, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
    ELEMENT(int, IntValue)   // TYPE=int, FIELD=IntValue
    ELEMENT(string, StrData) // TYPE=string, FIELD=StrData
    // and so on ...
};
```

Which will be expanded by the preprocessor to this code, which is what the compiler actually sees:

```
class MyClass
{
    bool getIntValue(int *field) const throw()
    {
        return x_->getIntValue(y_, field);
    }

    bool getStrData(string *field) const throw()
    {
        return x_->getStrData(y_, field);
    }

    // and so on ...
};
```

Comment: so the code after "##" must be a variable? In this case, FIELD is a variable.

Comment: No, it does not need to be a variable, it is whatever is specified in the `FIELD` parameter when the macro is invoked. `Value` and `Data` are not variables in my example.  Macros are basically just text substitution, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Another question is what is "const throw()" for? It will throw exceptions every time?

Comment: The `const` specifier means the method's implicit `this` parameter is a pointer to a `const` object, and so the method is not allowed to modify any members of the object. The `throw()` specifier (which is deprecated BTW, use `noexcept` instead) means the method is not allowed to throw any exceptions at all, if it does `std::terminate()` will be called to terminate the app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you, someone tried to be clever.

`#define` is used to textually replace one piece of text with another. The 2 arguments can be passed as a kind of arguments. Normally, such an argument is a token. However, thanks to ##, one can do token concatenation.

Let's take an example: ELEMENT(int, Cost);

This will result in the following code being injected:

```
bool getCost(int *field) const throw()
     ...
```

So as you can see, int is kept as token, while Cost is glued together into getCost.

I hope you found this in legacy code, cause using the preprocessor is considered bad coding in C++. The language hasn't been able to get rid of most usages. However they are providing alternatives to most common usages.
The `#include` and header guards have gotten replacements with the C++20 modules proposal.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Another question is what is "const throw()" for? It will throw exceptions every time?

Comment: While I agree that one should generally try to avoid preprocessor tricks in modern C++, it unfortunately remains the only way (or even more often, the only legible way) to achieve certain things. So I'd like to suggest that this response's condemnation of them is rather too strong. After all, `#include` is the preprocessor too.

Comment: #include is no longer relevant with C++20

Comment: const should be common knowledge with sufficient answers on this side

Comment: throw() is already deprecated since 2011, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec for details